# OpenFileMapping() can't find MMF created in COM DLL

Tags: c++, dll, com, ipc, memory-mapped-files

#### Context

I'm trying to send image data at runtime from a C++ .exe application to a DirectShow source filter implemented as a COM DLL. To do this, I'm trying to use memory-mapped files to perform IPC using a slightly modified version of the code taken from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14740/Fast-IPC-Communication-Using-Shared-Memory-and-Int). All clients and servers use the same `ipc.c` and `ipc.h`.

`hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, and I allow an external string to be used to set the `lpName`.

**Server**

I set the DLL debugger to `Command -> lync.exe` and `Debugger Type -> Mixed`, allowing me to debug the actual use of the filter. Server creation (static instance with function scope) succeeds and returns a valid handle.

```
HRESULT CVSourceStream::FillBuffer(IMediaSample *pms) {
    static osIPC::Server server(IPC_SERVER_ADDR); // filename shared by client/server   
    ... // set timestamp on sample
    BYTE *pData;
    pms->GetPointer(&pData);
    server.read(&pData, IPC_BLOCK_SIZE);
    return S_OK;
}
```

**Client**

However, when I attempt to open the file mapping when creating the `osIPC::Client` instance in my application, the `OpenFileMapping()` call fails by returning `NULL`, with the last error code being `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

`osIPC::Client client(IPC_SERVER_ADDR); // class instance member`

**Testing**

To test, I wrote a lightweight client/server pair of Visual Studio solutions that each have the corresponding types of initialization (non-static/static). Each solution is basically just a `main()` that creates the `osIPC::Client` or `osIPC::Server` then passes byte buffers across. Here, the `OpenFileMapping()` call succeeded.

Running my application in conjunction with the lightweight server succeeded, but combining the DLL with the lightweight client failed, leading me to suspect the filter was causing issues.

I tried appending `Global\\` to the file name passed to the `CreateFileMapping()` call to use the global namespace with no results.

#### Question

TL;DR: Is there a clear explanation for why the memory-mapped file created by `CreateFileMapping()` in my DLL, which is loaded by Lync.exe, doesn't seem to be visible to my client application, causing `OpenFileMapping()` to fail with an error code of `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`?

Comment: Codeproject.com code always lacks the "Only Works on My Machine" label.  `(LPCWSTR)m_sMemName` is incredibly bad code.  Don't waste your time on it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I've been trying to rapidly learn Windows/COM for my internship. When reading through the article, I found the non-Windows design fairly sound. Do you have suggestions to how I can fix the Windows interfacing code? Or should I just start from scratch and build up a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hans Passant pointed out, the referenced code made an unsafe typecast from `char *` to `LPWSTR`. By specifying my own Unicode strings explicitly and adjusting the constructors and internal variable types for `osIPC::Client` and `osIPC::Server`, I managed to get the IPC working.

Depending on whether `UNICODE` was defined as a macro and some other project settings, this was leading to unpredictable behavior of the overall code.